# patrolling in toxic areas or patrolling toxic areas

Tags: grammar

Robots are used for patrolling in toxic areas .
Robots are used for patrolling toxic areas .
Which is correct ? I found both usages in google .

Answer (score 1):

The word [patrol](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patrol) can be transitive or intransitive. Use transitively, the object is the place that is being patrolled:

> A security guard with a dog patrols **the building site at night**

Use intransitively, you have to attach the place using a preposition: in this example, **along**:

> Coastguards found a deserted boat while patrolling **along** the coast

So, you sentence is correct with or without the preposition **in**.

Answer (score 0):

"Patrolling in" means actually moving around inside. "Patrolling" without "in" *could* mean just moving around outside the border, stopping anyone from entering, and looking in to see if anything is wrong.

So I could imagine having robots "patrolling **in** the toxic area," with humans "patrolling the toxic area" outside. If they saw something they wouldn't (necessarily) enter the area - they could just send the robot.

Note that this is a subtle distinction - you could just as easily say "patrolling the area" even from the inside.